# Setting name servers in registrar vs NS records in name server

Tags: dns

My naive understanding was:

1. you tell the registrar that the name servers for `example.com` should be `dns1.example.net` and `dns2.example.net`.
2. upload a zone file to both `dns1.example.net` and `dns2.example.net` with some records.

I did not expect that 2. could include NS records. I thought NS records were part of step 1.

What is the purpose of having NS records in the name servers? How are NS records in used differently in 1. vs 2.?

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940395/mismatched-ns-records-at-dns-server) maybe touches on the topic a bit, but I'd like to get a deeper understanding.

Comment: This is something know as DNS delegation, checks this answer https://serverfault.com/a/530518/94862

Comment: That's a good overview, but still not super specific to my question. If I'm not reading it properly, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You touch an important point.

Indeed, `NS` records for a given domain name are both present in the parent zone (they are needed there for the proper delegation to occur), and in the zone itself.

If these 2 sets differ, you are in a situation called "lame delegation", and experts still disagree on which part is the more authoritative one, the records in the parent zone or in the child.

Now, both sets in fact server different purposes:

- the set in the parent zone tells you how to get to the child zone
- the set in the child zone tells you what server to query to have data about the content of the zone.

Imagine  for a moment that everywhere in the world the information about which nameservers are needed for each domain. You will then use this information to query them about records in the zone, like for `www`.
Everything is good.
But of course this information is not available worldwide like that (this was basically the situation before the DNS was invented), so a  mechanism is needed to achieve that. This is the purpose of the delegation associated with a tree structure: each node,  except the root, has a parent. So for things to work, when you (that is a recursive caching nameserver) start at the root, to find each subsequent nameservers "below" you will need to have the information "above", and hence you find the nameservers records in the parent zone.

When you feed a cache (by all your queries), you store the records as a collection in a zone. So the NS records needs to be there because they are tied to the zone, they are an integral part of it, like the SOA record.

Note that when you do the exact same query like `dig NS example.com` both at the parent nameservers and at the nameservers of this domain, the result should be the same (otherwise it is the lame delegation situation discussed at beginning), but with one important difference. In the results, one flag will be different: AA for Authoritative Answer will be set when you ask the nameservers of the zone but not set when you query the parent nameservers. The previous metaphor should now eplain this difference.

Also, for DNSSEC you have kind of a similar situation as you need again to build a chain, called the chain of trust. Each zone publishes a DNSKEY record (more than one in reality), and the parent zone publish a DS record for each DNSKEY record in the zone (again not 100% true but simpler to see it like that for now), and both are tied: the content of the DS record is some hash over the data in the DNSKEY record plus the zone name.

Comment: My understanding is that the ns host names/name servers given to registrar show where the zone is hosted. Then you query those hosts to get zone data. But if you’re querying those hosts/name servers don’t you already by definition know what at least one of the name servers is?

Comment: Yes, but then the recursive nameserver cache this data and will know later on which nameservers to query directly without  walking again from the parent.